# traffic from on-premisses to private subnet through DNS and ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

We have AWS Direct connect and routing set up to allow connectivity from on-premise to the VPCs and the other way around.

We need to access some application running on multiple EC2 from on-premise network only and not from internet.

My understanding is that we need:

1. DNS forwarding to a private Route 53 Hosted zone which will resolve all request to a
2. Internal ELB (not external) which in turn will serve request to the application hosted on private subnet EC2s.

So I do not see any need for any public Route 53 zones and no need for an external ELB.

Is my understanding correct or am I missing something about this architecture?

Comment: That is correct provided that your internal systems have DNS setup correctly to resolve private hosted zones.

Comment: Thank you for confirming.  Is there any better/easier way of securing that app is accessed only internally and traffic goes only through direct connect?

Comment: Create a new question as more details are required.